# How to sum 2D arrays in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, arrays

I am unable to add two 2D array in c
what could be the issue ? I am trying to add two multi-dimensional array from user input but the output is not right. 
Below is my code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main()
{
     int m,n,p,q,c,d,k;
     int first[10][10],second[10][10],sum[10][10];
     clrscr();
     printf("\nEnter the number of rows and columns of the first matrix");
     scanf("%d %d",&m,&n);
     printf("\nEnter the elements of the first matrix");
     for (c = 0;c < m;c++)
         for (d = 0;d < n;d++)
             scanf("%d",&first[c][d]);
     printf("\nEnter the number of rows and columns of the second matrix");
     scanf("%d %d",&p,&q);
     printf("\nEnter the elements of the second matrix");
     for (c = 0;c < p;c++)
         for (d = 0;d < p;d++)
             scanf("%d",&second[c][d]);
     for (c = 0;c < m;c++)
         for (d = 0;d < n;d++)
             for (k = 0;k < p;k++)
             {
                  sum[c][d] = first[c][k] + second[k][d];
             }
     printf("\nThe sum of the two matrices is : \n\n");
     for (c = 0;c < m;c++)
         for (d = 0;d < n;d++)
         {
              printf("%d",&sum[c][d]);
              if (d == n-1)
              {
                  printf("\n\n");
              }
         }
     getch();
}
```

Comment: c or c++ ? please format your code

Comment: c++. I am using it in TurboC++

Comment: `for (d = 0;d < p;d++)` seems to be wrong. `d` should run till `q`, isn't it?

Comment: @BBKiVines `int m,n,p,q,c,d,k;` -- If you had used more meaningful variable names, you may have had an easier time spotting one of your errors.

Comment: why are the two allowed to have different dimensions? if `m != p` or `n != q` your sum is wrong

Comment: When you say TurboC++ -- are you talking about the ancient Borland compiler for the late 80's early 90's? If so, do yourself a favor and either download the MS Software Development Kit 7.1 (that at least gets you VS10) or download MinGW which will get you gcc. Otherwise, the latest VS2017 Community is downloadable (but substantially larger by a factor of 8-10 over the earlier options)

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
for (d = 0;d < p;d++)
```

to this:

```
for (d = 0;d < q;d++)
```

when you populate your second array, since the dimension you used the first dimension, instead of the second.

---

Change this:

```
printf("%d", &sum[c][d]);
```

to this:

```
printf("%d", sum[c][d]);
```

since you want to print an integer.

---

PS: This is C, not C++.

Answer (score 0):

When you consider addition of two matrix, then the dimensions of two matrices should be identical. So you don't need to get input for dimensions of different matrix.
Secondly, try to use some meaningful variables and arrange the code properly so that it become easy for user to understand the code.
And Code you've provided is of C.

Problems in your code were:

```
   printf(" %d \n",&sum[c][d]);
```

and

```
    for (c = 0;c < m;c++)
    for (d = 0;d < n;d++)
    for (k = 0;k < p;k++)
    {
     sum[c][d] = first[c][k] + second[k][d];
    }
```

Improvement to Your code can be:

```
        #include<stdio.h>
        #include<conio.h>
        int main()
        {
         int m,n,c,d;
         int first[10][10],second[10][10],sum[10][10];
         clrscr();
         printf("\nEnter the number of rows and columns of the first matrix");
         scanf("%d %d",&m,&n);

         printf("\nEnter the elements of the first matrix");
         for (c = 0;c < m;c++)
           for (d = 0;d < n;d++)
              scanf("%d",&first[c][d]);

              printf("\nEnter the elements of the second matrix");  //Both the matrix 
              should have same dimensions in case of addition

         for (c = 0;c < m;c++)
           for (d = 0;d < n;d++)
             scanf("%d",&second[c][d]); 

         for (c = 0;c < m;c++)   //Addition matrix have same dimensions 
           for (d = 0;d < n;d++)
          {
             sum[c][d] = first[c][d] + second[c][d];
          }

         printf("\nThe sum of the two matrices is : \n\n");
         for (c = 0;c < m;c++)
            for (d = 0;d < n;d++)
             {
               printf(" %d \n",sum[c][d]);
             }

         getch();
         return 0;
        }
```

Comment: secondly ... you use same variable names ;)

Comment: I just fixed his code. So that it become easy for him to understand. @user463035818

Answer (score 0):

please check with all your indexes' ranges. you have some mistakes in there, one of them is **d** should run till **q** (I guess) use better names for your variables so that you can keep track in you mind of what you are doing. Also if you want to print the sum at the end, why use :

```
printf("%d", &sum[c][d]);
```

You don't need the **&** there.